# How to capture from sites like github?

Tags: emacs, javascript, org-mode, bookmarklet

I'm using the below bookmarklet with org-protocol/emacsclient to journal webpages (whitespace added):

```
javascript:location.href='org-protocol://capture://'+
encodeURIComponent(location.href)+'/'+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+
'/'+encodeURIComponent(window.getSelection())
```

It works for pretty much everything but notably github pages, and fails silently in that case. Is there some kind of URL rewriting going on? What do I need to change?

Comment: Just a random though: have you seen [this](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-get-a-permanent-link-from-file-view-to-permanent-blob-url)?

Comment: Interesting. So github might need a special grabber to trigger that automatically?

Comment: I'm thinking that's the case. Try it and see. :)

Answer (score 1):

Github was using a [Content Security Policy header](https://blog.github.com/2013-04-19-content-security-policy/) since 2013 that blocked bookmarklets via the `unsafe-inline` option:

```
CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY:
  default-src *;
  script-src 'self' assets-cdn.github.com jobs.github.com ssl.google-analytics.com secure.gaug.es;
  style-src 'self' assets-cdn.github.com 'unsafe-inline';
  object-src 'self' assets-cdn.github.com;
```

This was fixed in 2017 with a more explicit policy:

```
CONTENT-SECURITY-POLICY:
  default-src 'none';
  base-uri 'self';
  block-all-mixed-content;
  child-src render.githubusercontent.com;
  connect-src 'self' uploads.github.com status.github.com api.github.com www.google-analytics.com wss://live.github.com;
  font-src assets-cdn.github.com;
  form-action 'self' github.com gist.github.com;
  frame-ancestors 'none';
  frame-src render.githubusercontent.com;
  img-src 'self' data: assets-cdn.github.com identicons.github.com www.google-analytics.com collector.githubapp.com *.gravatar.com *.wp.com *.githubusercontent.com;
  media-src 'none';
  object-src assets-cdn.github.com;
  plugin-types application/x-shockwave-flash;
  script-src assets-cdn.github.com;
  style-src 'unsafe-inline' assets-cdn.github.com
```

**References**

- [Content Security Policy | The GitHub Blog](https://blog.github.com/2013-04-19-content-security-policy/)
- [GitHub's CSP journey | GitHub Engineering](https://githubengineering.com/githubs-csp-journey/)
- [GitHub's post-CSP journey | GitHub Engineering](https://githubengineering.com/githubs-post-csp-journey/)
- [866522 - Bookmarklets affected by CSP](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866522)
- [Implementing Content Security Policy - Mozilla Hacks - the Web developer blog](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/02/implementing-content-security-policy/)
- [A script tag injected into a page with a Content Security Policy that rejects inline scripts will not run [WORKING AS INTENDED] · Issue #2046 · greasemonkey/greasemonkey · GitHub](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/2046)